# Total values in a pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby, pandasql

My original dataframe is similar to the one below:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Variation' : ['A']*5 + ['B']*3 + ['A']*4, 
                  'id': [11]*4 + [12] + [15]*2 + [17] + [20]*4,
                 'steps' : ['start','step1','step2','end','end','step1','step2','step1','start','step1','step2','end']})
```

I wanted to create a pivot table from this dataframe for which I have used the below mentioned code:

```
df1=df.pivot_table(index=['Variation'], columns=['steps'], 
                          values='id', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

However, I also wanted to look at the total distinct count of the id's as well. Can someone please let me know how to achieve this? My expected output should be:

```
| Variation | Total id | Total start | Total step1 | Total step2 | Total end |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| A         | 3        | 2           | 2           | 2           | 3         |
| B         | 2        | 0           | 2           | 1           | 0         |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df1 = df1.join(df.groupby('Variation')['id'].nunique().rename('Total id'))
print(df1)
           end  start  step1  step2  Total id
Variation                                    
A            3      2      2      2         3
B            0      0      2      1         2
```

If need column after `Variation`:

```
c = ['id'] + df['steps'].unique().tolist()
df1 = (df1.join(df.groupby('Variation')['id'].nunique())
          .reindex(columns=c)
          .add_prefix('Total ')
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print(df1)
  Variation  Total id  Total start  Total step1  Total step2  Total end
0         A         3            2            2            2          3
1         B         2            0            2            1          0
```

Comment: How can I filter the values from pivot table? Let's say, I want to filter the 'Total end' value for Variation A and store it in a new variable. So my expected result would be ```new_var=3```

Comment: @hk2 - simpliest is remove from second solution `.reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)` and then use `new_var = df1.loc['Variation A','Total end']`